# distinct query with jpa,jasper report

Tags: java, jpa, jasper-reports

I am using `ireport-4.5.0,spring3.0.5RELEASE,jpa2`. I have an entity class named as User and having the attributes as follow
    userId,
    userName,
    password.I

Designed the jrxml by giving the fields as these three attributes names.If i give the jpa Query as From USer then it is working fine and giving the result. But i want the distinct values of userName(userName column allows duplicate values also)so i have given the jpaQuery as

```
SELECT userId,DISTINCT(userName),password FROM User
```

Then i am not getting the result.What is the problem with the query.

Hi here i am giving the code i am using

```
public User getUsers() throws Exception{
 Query uQuery = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u.userId,u.userName,u.password FROM User u GROUP BY u.userId,u.userName,u.password");
       List <User>listOfUsers = uQuery.getResultList();
       if (listOfUsers == null) {
           throw new ResourceNotFound();
        }
       for (Iterator iterator = listOfUsers.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            User userList = (User)iterator.next();

        }

       return userList;
```

Here i am getting the ClassCastException:java.lang.String cannot be cast to User.It is showing this exception in the for loop statement.I am new to JPA.Can you please explain how to iterate that list of objects.

Comment: Can any one give me the answer its very urgent to me.

Comment: Similar one, can refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4536802/366964 for retrieving selected attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put DISTINCT on a single column in JPQL or SQL.

You most likely need to use a group by,

SELECT u.userId,u.userName,u.password FROM User u group by u.userId, u.userName, u.password

Comment: Very thanks for giving the reply.But i have one more doubt i just improved the code.Can you just check it and can you tell me where i am wrong.