# JPQL: get the newest items

Tags: jpa, jpql

I’ve a table and Java Entity with these attributes:

> Notification
>
> -Id
>
> -scope
>
> -activity
>
> -user
>
> -creationTime
>
> -readTime (null --> new message)

How can I get the newest notifications per scope and activity with one JPQL statement?
Since JPA (Version 1.0, no Criteria API available) has no support for “SELECT TOP” or the LIMIT operator in the statement (only over the Entity Manager (em.setmax…)) I can’t find a solution…
Is there a way to do this task with only one JPQL statement?
Use native SQL to get LIMIT or TOP is no solution…

Example:

```
Notification 1
-Id:1
-scope:test
-activity:1
-user:user1
-cTime: 01.01.1999

Notification 2
-Id:2
-scope:test
-activity:1
-user:user1
-cTime: 02.02.2000


Notification 3
-Id:3
-scope:dev
-activity:2
-user:user1
-cTime: 01.01.1997
```

This should retrun: Notification 2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query, can alter the ordering of the field accordingly.

```
//-- MAX_RESULT_SIZE is the number of results to be fetched
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT n.scope, n.activity, MAX(n.Id) FROM Notification n GROUP BY n.scope, n.activity ORDER BY n.cTime DESC").setMaxResults(MAX_RESULT_SIZE);
```

For retrieving result from this query, which will be object array, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4536802/366964).

Comment: Sorry this doesn't solve the problem... Please have a look at the example. You have to group the enitities and then get the newest item for every group...

Comment: I think this isn't the solution. Grouping the id makes no sense... In addition I need the enities back from the em and not "n.scope, n.activity, n.Id"....

Comment: @mischu Are entries in the database in order as referred to cTime. If this is the case, I have updated the query.

Comment: The ids are a sequence and random so MAX(n.id) will not work... In addition "ORDER BY n.cTime DESC" will not work with JPA 1 because of the GROUP BY...