# accessing native query list using ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, jpa, nativequery

lets say i have a table `test` with columns `id` and `name`

on my bean i got this query

```
public List getTestList(){
  Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select * from test");
  List list = q.getResultList();
  return list;
}
```

and on my jsf page i have:

```
<ul>
    <ui:repeat id="resulta" value="#{testController.testList}" var="item"> 
        <li>#{item.id}</li>
    </ui:repeat>
</ul>
```

why do i get a `SEVERE: javax.el.ELException: /test.xhtml: For input string: "id"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *why do i get a SEVERE: javax.el.ELException: /test.xhtml: For input string: "id"*

Because a native query returns a `List<Object[]>`, not a `List<Test>`. You're basically attempting to access an `Object[]` array using a string such as `"id"` as index instead of an integer such as `0`. If you look closer to the stack trace, then you should have noticed the presence of `ArrayELResolver` a little further in the stack after the exception, which should already have hinted that `#{item}` is actually been interpreted as an array.

So, if you absolutely can't obtain it as a fullworthy `List<Test>` ([you can easily do inner joins using `@ManyToOne` and so on](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne)), then this should do to obtain the first column from the `SELECT` query:

```
<li>#{item[0]}</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The SELECT clause queries more than one column or entity, the results
>   are aggregated in an object array (Object[]) in the java.util.List
>   returned by getResultList().

In the first place, native query isn't required in your case. The result of native query returns a list of object array. You have to create JPQL query instead of native query.

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select t from Test t", Test.class);
List<Test> list = q.getResultList();
```

Comment: hi, actually i need it to be nativeQuery, because i need something like `"select t.*,nt.name from test as t Inner Join newTest as nt"`

Comment: @galao Try to describe your actual problem, it misleads people, wasting time on both the sides. Similar one, can refer here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4536802/366964