# JPQL: How to "SELECT new Foo(null, null... someValue, ..)?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

For example I have an entity

```
public class Foo {
   private String col1;
   private String col2;
   private String col3;
   private String col4;

   //getters and setters   
}
```

What I want to do is to `select` only `col3` and `col4`. But I already have a `Foo` constructor like below:

```
public Foo (String col1, String col2) {
   this.col1 = col1;
   this.col2 = col2;
}
```

Thus, I cannot have another constructor for `col3` and `col4` because it will have the same signature.

What I am trying to accomplish so far is to make a **complete** constructor like:

```
public Foo (String col1, String col2, String col3, String col4) {
   this.col1 = col1;
   this.col2 = col2;
   this.col3 = col3;
   this.col4 = col4;
}
```

But when I try to do something like below in my query

```
SELECT new Foo(null, null, f.col3, f.col4)
FROM Foo f
```

I get

`org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree`

Although when I try

```
SELECT new Foo(f.col1, f.col2, f.col3, f.col4)
FROM Foo f
```

It works as expected.

**EDIT:**

I tried

```
Select f.col3, col4..
```

and the error below was thrown

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result type [com.lala.entity.Foo]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result type [com.lala.entity.Foo]
```

Comment: To select individual columns, can refer here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4536802/366964 might help.

Comment: If it's a Integer instead of a String, do you know the solution ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try (but just a try)

```
SELECT new Foo(cast(null as string), cast(null as string), f.col3, f.col4)
FROM Foo f
```

or looking about cast() operator for JPQL if it is supported (I'm not sure)
else

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
List<Foo> list = session.createQuery("select f.col3, f.col4 from Foo f").list()
```

This is Hibernate specific and you don't need specific constructor for every projections; just create an empty constructor `Foo()` (at least protected, I don't remember if private is allowed) and let Hibernate inject value into `col3, col4` from your query (and `cast()` operator is supported if your underlying database support the function).

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is old but you can also do (if cast didn't work for you):

```
String query = "select new Pojo( " +
        " trim(:null), " +
        " trim(:null), " +
        " f.col3, " +
        " f.col4 " +
        " ) " +
        " from Foo as f ";

return em.createQuery(query, Pojo.class)
        .setParameter("null", null)
        .getResultList();
```

Edited:
JPA ignores literal columns when mapping them to the constructor arguments, so wrapped with trim to let JPA aware of the literal value.